# How to input the "realpath" of each file from a "while-loop" ind BASH script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, realpath

DESCRIPTION: Currently needing to input (or) pass the "realpath" of each file found hit found into a text file named "RESULTS.txt" that can be accessed by the user after the script runs.

ISSUE: Currently the syntax that i'm using to pass the code into the text file is failing. When I go to access the file it is blank. The following is the current code that is being used.

```
while read -r filename 
do
        filecount=$((filecount+1))

        tput rc    # return cursor to previously saved terminal line (tput sc)

        # print filename (1st line of output); if shorter than previous filename we need to erase rest of line

        filename="${filename%$'\r'}"
        printf "file: ${filename}${erase}\n"
        realpath "$filename" > RESULTS.txt

        # print our status bar (2nd line of output) on the first and every ${modcount} pass through loop;

        if   [ ${filecount} -eq 1 ]
        then
                printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n"

        elif [[ $((filecount % ${modcount} )) -eq 0 ]]
        then
                # for every ${modcount}th file we ...

                barspace=${barspace:1:100000}         # strip a space from barspace
                barhash="${barhash}#"                 # add a '#' to barhash
                printf "[${barhash}${barspace}]\n"    # print our new status bar
        fi


done < <(find "$dir_choice" -type f | sort -V )
```

...Pretty sure that the mistake that I am making is silly and is matter of syntax along with place ment not sure if I should be using `realpath "$filname" >> RESULTS` instead `realpath "$filename" > RESULTS.txt`

Comment: `>` truncate the file as oppose to `>>` which appends the output.

Comment: see `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*Redirecting\ Output' man bash`